# Error while loading shared libraries when compiling a SFML 2.0 project

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compiler-errors, g++, sfml

I tried to compile sfml 2.0.
At first I wrote this command:

```
g++ -c sprite.cpp -I sfml/include
```

Every files are on my desktop now and the folder that contains the sfml files is called sfml and it is on my desktop also.

After this command, I wrote:

```
g++ -o sprite sprite.o -L sfml/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

After this, I simply did:

```
./sprite
```

The problem is here. When I try to run it i get:

```
./sprite: error while loading shared libraries: libsfml-graphics.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loader could not find the library `libsfml-graphics.so.2`. It seems that this library is located under `sfml/lib`.
Once solution consists in adding the location to the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and exporting it before running your executable:
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:sfml/lib`